# Getting lots of "[error] Invalid method for processImg: resi" - when sending email - any idea?

Tags: civimail, error, mosaico

Getting lots of `[error] Invalid method for processImg: resi` - when sending email - any idea?

I think the actual error is getting cut off, as some of the errors read r, re, or res instead of resi.

This is happening during send of an email.

I am also getting `[error] Invalid params for processImg: resi`

Latest civicrm and wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a clean urls issue or frontend/backend or something like that. It's coming from mosaico, and yes the error is related to parsing of url params, and it's parsing it wrong.

Maybe first try just re-saving the mosaico config? Then if not maybe there is some clue in the browser's debug tools network tab when editing the email where you can see the full url. It will be the params for the `civicrm/mosaico/img` url.

Comment: I reloaded permalinks page, resaved mosaico settings, and looked up the image:

"https://pandemicresponse.columbia.edu/civicrm/mosaico/img/?src=https%3A%2F%2Fpandemicresponse.columbia.edu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fcivicrm%2Fpersist%2Fcontribute%2Fimages%2Fuploads%2FMonkeypox_Communications_Webinar_copy_2_1_5e2766ee106942d96ec332ea5266597c.png&method=resize&params=534%2Cnull"